# Why do the columns of the inverse of a matrix (defined as a linear operator) form an orthogonal basis in an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space over C and W be an inner product space over C with inner product <., .> and T:V --> W be a linear transformation. Find an orthogonal basis for V = R^3 with the inner product <., .>' = < T(u), T(v)> , if T= (Left multiplication by A) where 
A = a 3x3 matrix

I know the solution is finding the inverse of A and taking its columns as the orthogonal basis but I am not quite sure why

Comment: Simply put, they don't. Consider $A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The inner product of its columns is
$$\left\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle = 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 0 \neq 0.$$
However, you are missing some details, e.g. when you write "<.,.>' =" that sentence just kind of cuts off. Perhaps spend a moment to re-write your question to be clear.

Comment: @Arkamis sorry about that I just edited the question so it makes sense

Comment: I appreciate the work done in rewriting the Question.  The new inner product $\langle u, v \rangle = \langle Au, Av \rangle $ has an orthogonal basis consisting of the columns of $A^{-1}$ because these columns are $A^{-1} e_j$ for standard basis vectors $e_j$, $j=1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find some matrix $A$ that acts like the linear transformation $T : V \to W$, or in other words, given $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, we want to find some matrix $A$ such that $Av = w$.

Furthermore, we are equipping $W$ with an inner product, so we can compute $\langle w_1, w_2\rangle_W$. Note that I am using subscript $W$ around the inner product brackets to be explicitly clear which space I am computing the inner product over.

Now, we want our matrix $A$ to have the following properties: it is $3 \times 3$ and that it forms a unitary matrix. If we assume $V,W$ to be vector spaces over the reals, then we sometimes call the matrix *orthogonal*. In any case, we will ensure that its **rows** are orthogonal vectors.

Let's take a moment to ask "why rows, why not columns?" Intuitively, recall that when multiplying by a column vector, we're essentially taking the inner product of each *row* of the matrix with the vector. In fact, it won't matter, because unitary matrices enjoy the property that their rows *and* columns are orthogonal (in fact orthonormal) with respect to the usual inner product.

Now, since we have $\langle u, v\rangle_V = \langle T(u), T(v)\rangle_W$, it is quite simple to find such a matrix. In fact, it is the most elementary matrix you can find!

Comment: Perhaps I phrased the question incorrectly. I am given a 3x3 matrix A with real entries and am asked to find a orthogonal basis for V given this information. The solution involves taking the inverse of A but I still do not understand why. @Arkamis

Comment: Then, as I initially mentioned, perhaps you should spend some time writing the question completely.

Comment: Reason being, it is hard to know exactly what you are asking without complete detail. Reason two being that there may be multiple solutions for this problem, and since you're asking about a specific technique it is necessary for us to figure out precisely what technique you're confused about.